# Translation Function missing text-domain

Tags: functions, errors

> **WARNING**: Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function `esc_attr_x`, with the arguments 'Search for:', 'label'

I'm Getting this error on a theme I bought. Not sure what the mistake on this is. On the `searchform.php` file I have:

```
< input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="
< ?php echo get_search_query() ? >" name="s" title=" < ?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ? >" / >
```

I tried removing the spaces in the 'Search for:' area but didn't change the error I was getting.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the functions [signature](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr_x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From WordPress Codex ([Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr_x)):

```
<?php $translated_text = esc_attr_x( $text, $context, $domain ) ?>
```

The `$domain` is optional. That´s the reason it´s a warning. Do you have debug set to true? If you want to fix it you have to add the text-domain.

```
esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'TEXT-DOMAIN-FROM-THEME' )
```

You can find the text-domain in other translatable strings like this one.

General: It´s better to contact the theme-developer in this case. You paid money - you can expect that it does not have any errors or warnings.